# MILP constraint for cyclic task scheduling

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I am working on developing a MILP mathematical model which deals with cyclic tasks. I at a stage where I have to design constraints in this regard. here is the simplified version of the problem.

the are 4 tasks of A type: [A1, A2, A3, A4]. I need a constraint that

- first make sure the tasks are in order
- second, in the planning horizon, after task A4 is again A1. this cycle will go on till the planning horizon ends.

I have created constraints to verify the sequence of tasks:

X_A: = 1 if task A is being done

index a: tasks {1, 2, .... , A}

sum over planning horizon(X_a) >= sum over planning horizon(X_a+1)  for all a in {1,2, ... A-1}

I am stuck on writing a constraint to make sure within the planning horizon after the last task it goes and start the first task and repeat the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Google_ortool's CP-SAT solver (python API) to solve the problem.
So if your total horizon length where you need to plan the task = 51 units,
and your tasks are `tasks = {"a1" : 2, "a2" : 3, "a3" : 7, "a4" : 9, "a5" : 1}` where "a1" is task and 2 is the length of the task, then solution will look like :

```
(cycle, task ==> whether task was performed ==> task duration)
(0, 'a1') ==> 1 ==> 2
(0, 'a2') ==> 1 ==> 3
(0, 'a3') ==> 1 ==> 7
(0, 'a4') ==> 1 ==> 9
(0, 'a5') ==> 1 ==> 1
(1, 'a1') ==> 1 ==> 2
(1, 'a2') ==> 1 ==> 3
(1, 'a3') ==> 1 ==> 7
(1, 'a4') ==> 1 ==> 9
(1, 'a5') ==> 1 ==> 1
(2, 'a1') ==> 1 ==> 2
(2, 'a2') ==> 1 ==> 3
(2, 'a3') ==> 0 ==> 0
(2, 'a4') ==> 0 ==> 0
(2, 'a5') ==> 0 ==> 0

total length = 49, which is less than the horizon length 51, we
cant take up a3 because its length is 7 and 49 + 7 >= 51. So we
stop at a2 only.
```

code listing in python

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp
import numpy as np

planning_horizon_length = 51

# tasks and their corresponding duration
tasks = {"a1" : 2,
         "a2" : 3,
         "a3" : 7,
         "a4" : 9,
         "a5" : 1
       }

total_task_length = sum(tasks.values())

# how many cycles we would require
num_cycles = int(np.ceil(planning_horizon_length / total_task_length))

model = cp.CpModel()

# decision variable : for each cycle - task whether it will be done or not
cycle_tasks = []
dv_cycle_task = {}
for i in range(num_cycles):
    for j in tasks:
        dv_cycle_task[(i, j)] = model.NewBoolVar("cycle : " + str(i) + " & " + "task : " + str(j))
        cycle_tasks.append((i, j))

# precedence constraint : for each cycle, a1 should come before a2 and so on
for i, j in enumerate(cycle_tasks):
    if i < len(cycle_tasks) - 1:
        model.Add(dv_cycle_task[cycle_tasks[i]] >= dv_cycle_task[cycle_tasks[i + 1]])
 
# capture total run length
total_run_length = model.NewIntVar(0, planning_horizon_length, "")
model.Add(total_run_length == sum(dv_cycle_task[(i, j)] * tasks[j] for (i, j) in cycle_tasks))

# total run length should be lower than planning_horizon_length
model.Add(total_run_length <= planning_horizon_length)


# we want total run length should be as close to planning_horizon_length i.e. 51
model.Maximize(total_run_length - planning_horizon_length)

solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model) 

# objective function value : how extra we went
solver.Value(total_run_length)

# inspect the solution
for (i, j) in cycle_tasks:
    print(str((i, j)) + " ==> " + str(solver.Value(dv_cycle_task[(i, j)])) + " ==> " + str(solver.Value(dv_cycle_task[(i, j)]) * tasks[j]))
```